# Efficient way to be update grand child records in c# using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have to update a column 'PPMOProjectID' in the table, but in such way that if it is empty and tricky part is

I have a scope of only parent child relation ship in the table like if MP- master parent, P- parent, Child - C:

```
ID   ParentID PPMOProjectID
MP1     NULL     NULL //updating here by 889
P1      MP1      898 //It should not update, because it contains already value
P2      MP1      NULL//it should update by 889 if it is empty else skip it
C1       P1      NULL//Here it should update by 898
C2       P1      NULL//Here it should update by 898
C3       P2      NULL//Here it should update by 889
```

As per above logic :When I updating PPMOProjectID in parent record, I have to check all children's and master children's , if the record is empty I have to update by Immediate record parent, it that parent is empty and need to update by master column ID, if parent record has column ID , should update by Parent ID itself.

This should be done in C# and LINQ , I have tried by below logic :

```
var childProjects = db.Projects.Where(m => m.AC_ParentProject_ID == AC_ProjectID).ToList();
var updateRecords = new List<Project>();
 while (childProjects.Count == 0)
 {

   foreach(var item in childProjects)
    {
      updateRecords = childProjects.Where(m => m.AC_ParentProject_ID == item.AC_ParentProject_ID).ToList();
      //saving logic here..
    }
  }
```

But how to get grand childrens it should keep on checking.

I am struggling to find a way for above requirement. can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from the master row (MP) and go down to iterate in parent rows (P) and update them (where it is needed i.e. if `PPMOProjectID` is null). For every iteration of parent, you can enter a new iteration in their children (C) and update their `PPMOProjectID` with the parent's `PPMOProjectID` (if it is not null) because the parent's `PPMOProjectID` already has the correct value assigned to it.

In the code below, I used the names you defined in your table. If you have different names in you entity, you can change them accordingly. The first four lines you might not need since you have probably covered the logic of retrieving the master record and setting its PPMOProjectID, but I am adding them just for clarity.

```
string AC_ProjectID = "MP1"; // you might be getting this value from somewhere else and not declaring it like this
string parentPPMOID = "889"; // the value which you are updating
var masterParent = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == AC_ProjectID); //get the master parent itself
masterParent.PPMOProjectID = parentPPMOID;
var parentProjects = db.Projects.Where(m => m.ParentID == AC_ProjectID).ToList();

foreach(var parentProject in parentProjects)
{
    if(parentProject.PPMOProjectID == null)
    {
        // assign the PPMOProjectID to the parent
        parentProject.PPMOProjectID = masterParent.PPMOProjectID;
    }
    var childProjects = db.Projects.Where(c => c.ParentID == parentProject.ID).ToList();
    foreach(var childProject in childProjects) 
    {
        if(childProject == null) 
        {
            //assign the child PPMOProjectID with the parent PPMOProjectID since it already was set in line 11 (of this code snippet)
            childProject.PPMOProjectID = parentProject.PPMOProjectID;           
        }       
    }   
}

//saving logic here..
```

**EDIT:**
If the depth can go on, you can use recursion to go down to children as much as it is needed. The following method can solve your problem.

```
public void UpdatePPMORecursively(Project project, string ppmo)
{
    if (project.PPMOProjectID == null)
    {
        project.PPMOProjectID = ppmo;
    }

    var childrenProjects = db.Projects.Where(c => c.AC_ParentProject_ID == project.ID).ToList();
    if (childrenProjects.Count() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var childProject in childrenProjects)
    {
        UpdatePPMORecursively(childProject, project.PPMOProjectID);
    }
}
```

You can call the method with something like this. I will use the same context variables as before:

```
string AC_ProjectID = "MP1"; // you might be getting this value from somewhere else and not declaring it like this
string parentPPMOID = "889"; // the value which you are updating
var masterParent = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == AC_ProjectID); //get the master parent itself
UpdatePPMORecursively(masterParent, parentPPMOID );
```

Note that performance wise, it might not be the best solution in the world, since you are dealing with a database.

Comment: Thank you @granit , but worst part is even child project may have again child projects and may loop goes on until records exists but there is limit, can you suggest something in such case?

Comment: Okay, because I had the impression you only have these three levels of depth. In such cases it is best to use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). I will update my answer as soon as possible.